# SUM of a column in Join Query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables.

`fundraisers`

```
    fundraiserId fundDescription fundName 
        14          testingfund     test      
        15          analysis        testing
```

`fundraisingusers`

```
     fundraisinguserId amount fundraiserId userId
        1               1000    14          12
        2               2000    14          13
        3               5000    15          14
```

`users`

```
    userId  firstName
     12       xyz
     13       pqr
     14       abc
```

I am trying to display all fundraisers from `fundraisers` table with sum of amount from `fundraisingusers` table and user details from `user` table.I am writing query something like this.

```
    SELECT f.fundraiserId as fundraiserId,
    f.fundDescription as fundDescription,
    f.fundName as fundName,
    sum(fu.amount as amount),
    fu.userId as userId FROM fundraisers as f 
    left outer join fundraisingusers as fu on f.fundraiserId =
    fu.fundraiserId left outer join users as u on fu.userId =
    u.userId";
```

Now i am able to get all the fundraisers with fundnames,fundDescriptions.But in amount i am not able to get the sum.

For example in fundraisingusers table i have two rows with same fundraiserId.Therefore in query as i am giving condition ON f.fundraiserId =fu.fundraiserId it is displaying fundraiser with fundraiserId 14 twice in the output with amounts showing empty.Can anyone tell how can i return unique rows from fundraising table if it has same fundraiserId more than once and also return sum of the amounts from fundraisingusers table with same fundraiserId.

My expected output is something like this.

```
    fundraiserId fundDescription fundName   amount userId
       14         testingfund      test      3000    
       15         analysis         testing   5000
```

I want to display all fundraisers.If same fundraiserId is there then i want to display it only once with amount field added.In userId column if more than one users donate for same fundraiser then same fundraiser should display with sum of amounts.

Comment: If you want the sum, use `group by`.

Comment: You need to use group by clause of sql. Group by fundraiser id and sum its amount.

Comment: But i want to display fundraiser only once.Now it is displaying twice

Comment: If you want a total `amount` broken down by `fundraiserId`, how would the `userId` fit into that? If you list all the individual users the `sum` of the amount would not be for the fundraiser but only for the specific user for a given fundraiser. `user join not mandatory` is confusing as both are different ways of breaking down the data. What is it you want? The total amount per fundraiser or the total amount per user in each fundraiser?

Comment: @SachinHR If you are summing the amount per user you will see duplicate fundraiser entries as there is multiple users per fundraiser. If you only want the amount per fundraiser you need to remove the user from your query and only sum the amount by fundraisers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a total amount per fundraiser you can do it similar to the below:

```
select 
  fr.fundraiserId, 
  fr.fundDescription, 
  fr.fundName, 
  sum(fru.amount) as amount
from fundraisers as fr
join fundraisingusers fru on fru.fundraiserId = fr.fundraiserId
group by
  fr.fundraiserId, 
  fr.fundDescription, 
  fr.fundName
```

**Output**

```
|fundraiserId  |  fundDescription  |  fundName  |  amount |  
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|14            |  testingfund      |  test      |  3000   |
|15            |  analysis         |  testing   |  5000   |
```

---

**See [SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7caa9/3)**

---

However, if you are looking for a total amount per **user** per fundraiser then you can do it similar to this:

```
select 
  fr.fundraiserId, 
  fr.fundDescription, 
  fr.fundName, 
  sum(fru.amount) as amount,
  u.firstName
from fundraisers as fr
join fundraisingusers fru on fru.fundraiserId = fr.fundraiserId
join users as u on u.userId = fru.userId
group by
  fr.fundraiserId, 
  fr.fundDescription, 
  fr.fundName,
  u.firstName
```

**Output**

```
| fundraiserId | fundDescription | fundName | amount | firstName |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| 15           | analysis        | testing  | 5000   | abc       |
| 14           | testingfund     | test     | 2000   | pqr       |
| 14           | testingfund     | test     | 1000   | xyz       |
```

---

**See [SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7caa9/7)**

---

> I want to display only fundraisers with status=1 like where
>   f.status='1'.Where i have to place this code?

If you like to add a `where` clause you can add it before the `group by`, similar to:

```
select 
  fr.fundraiserId, 
  fr.fundDescription, 
  fr.fundName, 
  sum(fru.amount) as amount
from fundraisers as fr
join fundraisingusers fru on fru.fundraiserId = fr.fundraiserId
where fr.status = 1
group by
  fr.fundraiserId, 
  fr.fundDescription, 
  fr.fundName
```

---

**See [SqlFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e614/2) with Where Clause**

---

Comment: Can u tell if i can use where clause in this sql query for specifying condition?

Comment: @SachinHR Shouldn't be a problem. Which conditions though?

Comment: I want to display only fundraisers with status=1 like where f.status='1'.Where i have to place this code?

Comment: @SachinHR You can add it after the `join`, before the `group by`. I added an example. To apply the `where` clause to the `user` breakdown, just add it at the same location in the other query.

Comment: yup working ..thank you very much.The answers you gave and in the manner how you gave were really helpful and understandable

Comment: one issue i am facing.If different users donate amount for same fundraiser then it is displaying again as two fundraisers with different amounts.For same user it is working fine

Comment: As you have mentioned in your previous comment if different users are involved then duplicate records are displayed.Is there any way to solve this issue like the same user?

Comment: @SachinHR Fundraisers are duplicated if different users have amounts against the same fundraiser. If it is the same user all their amounts get summed up as a single record. You would not be able to sum up the complete fundraiser amount from all users and show "A" user in the same record. Which user would you show if the summed amount is the result of all Users? If you don't want the user breakdown, then don;t include them in the query.

Comment: The total amount gets summed up even for different users when i give condition based on fundraiserId that is where fundraiserId = fundraiserId.But when displaying all fundraisers it is duplicating records if different users donate for same fundraiser

Comment: Is it not possible to show sum of all amount for different users while displaying all fundraisers without duplicate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156112/discussion-between-fran-and-sachin-hr).

Answer (score 0):

You need  gruop by

```
  SELECT f.fundraiserId as fundraiserId,
    f.fundDescription as fundDescription,
    f.fundName as fundName,
    sum(fu.amount as amount),
    fu.userId as userId 
    FROM fundraisers as f 
    left outer join fundraisingusers as fu on f.fundraiserId = fu.fundraiserId 
    left outer join users as u on fu.userId =     u.userId
    group by  f.fundraiserId as fundraiserId,
    f.fundDescription as fundDescription,
    f.fundName as fundName,   
    fu.userId as userId ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Join `fundraisers` table with `fundraisingusers` table and do a `COUNT(*)`.

```
SELECT fr.fundraiserId ,fr.fundDescription ,fr.fundName,count(*) AS amount
FROM fundraisers fr
INNER JOIN fundraisingusers fau ON fr.fundraiserId =fau.fundraiserId
GROUP BY fr.fundraiserId ,fr.fundDescription ,fr.fundName
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way around using inner query without a join, without a group by.

```
Select fundraiserId, fundDescription, fundName, (select sum(amount) from fundraisingusers where fundraisers.fundraiserId = fundraisingusers.fundraiserId) as amount  from fundraisers
```